# Listbox RemoveAt throws an exception

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

I have a problem understanding what's going on in here. My ListBox (lst1) is databinded to a file-list (list type), and I want to remove several items from that list. Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't - really annoying and stupid, I really don't see the problem with my code... If I select 3 or more different items, after deleting the last one, it throws "out of range" exception! Funny thing is,sometimes it doesn't... I know there's some hidden trick or thing I don't know of, so please help me if you can.

```
private void btnSub_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (lst1.Items.Count != 0)
    {
        lst1.BeginUpdate();
        foreach (int i in lst1.SelectedIndices)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(i.ToString()); //for debug purposes, int i remains as it should be, but still I get "out of range" exceptions ?!
            fileList.RemoveAt(i);
        }

        lst1.SelectedItems.Clear(); // just in case - resetting my selection
        lst1.DataSource = null;
        lst1.DataSource = fileList; //resetting my bindlist so it displays the change i've made.
        lst1.EndUpdate();
    }       
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("List is empty, nothing to remove...");
    }
}
```

Here's the error I'm getting.

> Unhandled exception. Index was out of range Must be non-negative and less than size of the collection. Parameter name: index

Comment: You do realize that when you remove item from a list, indexes might change since list size changes? Consider ["a","b","c"] and you remove item from index 1, then you'll have items only in indexes 0 and 1. If you then try to remove index 2, it's out of range.

Comment: I thought of that. Maybe I should rebound my list after every foreach cycle, and hope that selectedindices will reflect the new values ?

Comment: Is that WinForms or WPF? WPF's ListBox doesn't have the `SelectedIndices` property, I suppose.

Comment: plain and simple windows forms :)

Answer (score 1):

Think about it. You are deleting all the selected indicies. The indicies of the other items change as soon as you delete the first one.

So you have:

```
[0] Item 0
[1] Item 1
[2] Item 2
[3] Item 3
[4] Item 4
```

Lets say you select 1, 2, 3. First it deletes Item 1, your list becomes:

```
[0] Item 0
[1] Item 2
[2] Item 3
[3] Item 4
```

Then you delete 2:

```
[0] Item 0
[1] Item 2
[2] Item 4
```

And now you are trying to delete 3, but oops, 3 doesn't exist, out of range!

You are deleting items you don't intend to delete. You wanted to delete 1, 2 and 3, but you ended up deleting only 1 and 3, skipping 2. At other times this may delete items (if you have non-sequential indicies selected) that you actually wanted to keep.

**EDIT**

Really what you should be doing is using good MVC code and deleting the items from the model, and letting the view update itself. Pass the indicies (or better yet, the `SelectedItems`) to the view, and tell the view to delete them.

Comment: Yeah, I realise that, the whole list kinda changes itself, while I delete a certain value. Thanx for the answer, I still can't vote you up, but that's the problem, I think. I was thinking it might be the problem too, but wasn't sure.

Comment: See the edit, there is a better way that follows good MVC/MVVM practices.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
using System.Linq;

List<string> filesToRemove = lst1.SelectedIndices.Cast<int>().Select(i => fileList[i]).ToList();
foreach (string fileToRemove in filesToRemove)
    fileList.Remove(fileToRemove);
```

Version without LINQ:

```
List<string> filesToRemove = new List<string>(); 
foreach(int indexToRemove in lst1.SelectedIndices)               
    filesToRemove.Add(fileList[indexToRemove]);
foreach (string fileToRemove in filesToRemove)
    fileList.Remove(fileToRemove);
```

I hope it works :)

Comment: This actually works... But I hate copying > pasting code which I don't understand :P Linq library is so scary for me ATM, I am still struggling to get the basics :) The goal is to make list out from your selected files and then to remove that list out of the original one, right ?

Comment: @NerdBg Yes, first, you have to find the file names to remove, and then you should remove them from `fileList`. If you dont want to use LINQ, then use this: `List<string> filesToRemove = new List<string>(); foreach(int indexToRemove in lst1.SelectedIndices) filesToRemove.Add(fileList[indexToRemove]);`

Comment: Actually this has a little bug, too... If you make a list according to selected items, and then remove it, using filelist.remove in the example above, it will search for a string that matches the one in the list for removal, and **the first one which has been found** gets deleted. It ruins the order of a list. if I had 2 same entries on a different locations, the first entry gets deleted, always, no matter I wanted to remove the other one...

Answer (score 0):

With Your help, I've learned what was the cause for the problem. I just added one counter to my original code and now it works just fine. Counter keeps track of deleted items, and sets the index accordingly. I think it's safer to work with the items index than to refer to them using their content - so there would be no confusion. This solution is based on Beyer's answer, but thanks to all others who bothered to help a newb coder :) Of course, there are some more advanced tools to handle this problem, but for now - here it is.

```
private void btnSub_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (lst1.Items.Count != 0)
        {
            lst1.BeginUpdate();
            int j = 0; // it counts the number of items deleted               
            foreach (int i in lst1.SelectedIndices)
            {
                fileList.RemoveAt(i - j); // index is j positions lesser than it originally was.
                j++; // increasing the deleted items count.
            }

            lst1.DataSource = null;
            lst1.DataSource = fileList; //resetting my bindlist so it displays the change i've made.
            lst1.EndUpdate();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("List is empty, nothing to remove...");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Good idea. It'll work as far as `SelectedIndices` are sorted ascending.